# Bash/ echo and pattern

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file which starts with "`xx`", I want to find it and do some bash commands on it.

In order to find it, I wrote the next command:

```
b= 'echo $(ls -r /var/www/xx*)'
```

But it say that  `No such file or directory`, while `xxbr7.log` is there.

How I can find it?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- you can't reliably use `ls` output in scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a space after the `=` so it is interpreting the entire `'echo $(ls -r /var/www/xx*)'` string as a command to execute (with the variable `b` set to an empty string in its environment.)

If you're trying to set `b` to the string `echo /var/www/xxbr7.log` then you want:

```
b='echo $(ls -r /var/www/xx*)'
```

with no space after the `=` character.

If you're trying to set it to just the string `/var/www/xxbr7.log` then you can simplify it:

```
b=$(ls -r /var/www/xx*)
```

Or for the special case where there's only one file doing `$(ls -r /var/www/xx*)` is unnecessary, you could just say `/var/www/xx*`

```
b=/var/www/xx*
```

Comment: This is only correct if there is one and only one file matching the glob. That is what OP implies, but future readers may be confused.

Comment: `/var/www/xx*` doesn't reverse the order of the items

Comment: Since we know [parsing ls is bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), we can get the "last" matching value far more cheaply and safely using bash arrays: `arr=( xx* ); last="${arr[@]: -1}"`

Comment: @kojiro, there's no indication the OP only wants the last value though

Comment: @JonathanWakely Presumably the OP only wants one value, and he sorted the output of `ls` in lexical reverse order, so I inferred that he wanted the lexical last value. If he wants multiple values, his question certainly doesn't make that clear.

Comment: @JonathanWakely There is a missing single quote in the line `b='echo $(ls -r /var/www/xx*)`. Please fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command:

```
find . -name 'mystring*'
```

to find.